# Using two getElementByIds

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, lit-element

Is it possible to do something like:

```
this.getElementById('first-id').getElementById('second-id')?
```

When I do this, I get an error "getElementById(...).getElementById is not a function.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I am able to console log the first-id element, but not the second (when I do `this.getElementById('second-id')`). I assume it is because my DOM is not completely loaded.

However, I thought since it loaded the first-id element, I'll be able to do another getElementById as the first part is loaded and the next element is nested/a child of the first-id element.

Can someone explain why this logic doesn't work?

Comment: `getElementById` is not a scoped function (unlike `querySelector`), so no. `getElementById` is a member of the `Document` object, not the `HTMLElement` object.

Comment: "I assume it is because my DOM is not completely loaded." - no, I think it's because you don't yet understand how method-chaining works. A method-chain is _not_ a promise-chain, but a promise-chain is a method-chain,

Comment: Are you trying to access children of the element? Try childNodes instead, and refer to CertainPerformance answer below why what you are doing is not going to work, or why you should not do it in the first place.

Comment: Are you just trying to select two elements with different Ids? In what context are you using `this.getElementById('second-id')`? It might help to include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most answers here are correct and will help the OP implement the solution. This will try to answer *Is it possible to do something like:*, which is what OP asked originally:

```
this.getElementById('first-id').getElementById('second-id')
```

[`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is a Document interface method and is only available on the [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object. It is not available on the `Element`, and `this.getElementById('first-id').getElementById` will be equal to `undefined`. `undefined` is not a function and can't be invoked, hence the error.
It makes sense that `getElementById()` is only available in the `Document` interface as an `ID` is (ideally) supposed to be a unique in the DOM. So, providing the function inside other elements is not **as useful.**

`querySelecetor()` is both a [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) method and is available on both the objects.

That is why you can do something like :

```
document.querySelector('#first-id').querySelector('#second-id')
```

(Searches for `#second-id` child of `#first-id`)

Comment: `document.querySelector('#first-id').querySelector('#second-id')` won't work unless `#first-id` is an ancestor of `#second-id` btw (as [`Element.querySelector` uses the `Element` as the start of an implicit selector search scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector). Also the second call won't be made if `#first-id` does not exist on the page because the JS engine will complain of a `null`-dereference.

Answer (score 10):

An element with a given ID is supposed to be *absolutely unique* in a document. There should never be more than one element with the same ID. So, calling `getElementById` on an *element* to search among its children, if it were possible (which it isn't), wouldn't make a whole lot of sense - instead, search from the *whole document*. You should only need

```
document.getElementById('second-id')
```

Comment: "So, calling getElementById on an element to search among its children doesn't make a whole lot of sense" - it's not just that it doesn't make sense - it's _completely undefined_.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly chain it using [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), but you should never need to use this as ids should be unique.

E.g, something like this:

```js
var selected = document.querySelector('#first-id #second-id');
console.log(selected);
```

```html
<div id="first-id">
  <div id="second-id">1</div>
</div>
<div id="second-id">2</div>
<!-- Don't use duplicate ids - this is just for demonstration -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something weird like the following, but it's silly.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        alert(document.getElementById("parent").ownerDocument.getElementById("child").textContent);
    }, false);
</script>

<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Yo</div>
</div>
```